# Evaluating $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{7-2x}^3 \frac{u^3}{1+u^2}du$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Evaluate following expression by using The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{7-2x}^3 \frac{u^3}{1+u^2}du$$

Comment: I'd switch the limits and (thereby) the sign...

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting something, like the variable of integration. You can use fundamental theorem of calculus to F(3) - F(7-2x) to get the definite integral, where F is the antiderivitive.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the antiderivative of this function.

Comment: The question says to use part 1 of the fundamental theorem of calculus to get the answer. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: For the integrand, use polynomial long division

Comment: @Shelby What's your question?

Comment: I'm just wanting to know how to solve this problem. The lower limit makes it so that I am confused on how to go about solving this integral.

Comment: @Shelby Did it help?

Comment: @Shelby you don't need to compute $F$ explicitly, just differentiate: $\bigl(F(3)-F(7-x)\bigr)'=0-F'(7-x)\cdot(-1)=f(7-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{7-2x}^3 \frac{u^3}{1+u^2}du=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^3 \frac{u^3}{1+u^2}du-\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{7-2x} \frac{u^3}{1+u^2}du$$